# Where to store images to be shown on CodePlex documentation?

Tags: codeplex

I have a project at CodePlex and I have lots of documentation pages. Previously I stored images on Facebook and pointed to the external URL of these images but the URL changes from time to time and I have to re-do all the image links.

Where can I store the images so they stay forever?

Is there a way to store these images together with the HTML inside CodePlex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach your image in a page in your project documentation area, it looks like you store your image with a link and use it for any purpose (discussion, Documentation...)

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to put your images on image sharing websites. It seems like most people use Imgur to share their pictures, so you can use it and link to it from the HTML code in your documentation webpages (using `<img src="">`)

It is quite debatable regarding what services keep your files online for the longest period of time, but generally it is how much you trust in the service you are using.

As for the second question, there seems to be [some guide](https://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Wiki%20Links#Image) regarding the use of the images in the wiki (I am assuming that it is the documentation you are talking about). It seems like you can upload images to the wiki and link it from the documentation itself.

Comment: OK thanks. As I don't have experience with these sites, do you think I gur will keep the images for at least one or two years?

Comment: It has been up for almost 4 years, so I guess so?